# Move docker data (images and containers) to separate drive with different FS

Tags: docker

I am planning to move docker data (images and containers) to separate drive as they require many space.

As I know I can move `/var/lib/docker` to separate drive and create soft link to it.  But I have read that BTRFS is a best file system option for docker.

But I suspect it is not enough to format external drive to BTRFS and move existing folder to it.  As I see the content of this folder depends on the using file system.

How can I move (recreate) docker folder (images and containers) on the external drive with different file system correctly?

Answer (score 6):

As you stated simply moving or copying the docker images/containers from the default AUFS to BTRFS formatted drive is not going to work. So as a first step, you can commit all your containers as images and use `docker save` commands to save the images as .tar files and then once you have prepped docker to use btrfs, you run `docker load` to load the images into the new storage driver.

The steps would be roughly as follows - this is what i did in my Ubuntu 14.10 box -

- Save your images 
  `docker save IMAGEID > /tmp/redis.tar`
- Prep btrfs

```
 mkfs.btrfs /dev/sdb
 mkdir /var/lib/docker-btrfs
 mount /dev/sdb /var/lib/docker-btrfs/
```

- Stop docker and set docker to utilize btrfs and run it.

```
service docker stop
docker -d -s btrfs  --graph="/var/lib/docker-btrfs"  -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock
```

The above step can also be accomplished by modifying /etc/default/docker.

- Load the images.

```
docker load --input /tmp/redis.tar
```

You should be able to see the images and run containers from here. For containers, you can also try `export` and `import` methods, i have never tried that one though.