# how to migrate docker to use a different storage driver?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, docker, btrfs

I have a server running docker with btrfs storage driver. How can I migrate it to use a different storage driver? I would like to use overlay2.

I've tried to migrate using the instructions [here](https://docs.docker.com/storage/storagedriver/overlayfs-driver/):

- stop docker
- rename /var/lib/docker to /var/lib/docker.bak
- add {"storage-driver": "overlay2"} to /etc/docker/daemon.json
- copy /var/lib/docker.bak to /var/lib/docker (to "get rid" of any btrfs snapshots)
- start docker

But after this migration, no containers are present anymore.

I suppose because the directory still has data in `/var/lib/docker/btrfs`, and not in `/var/lib/docker/overlay2` (they have different "layout", renaming btrfs to overlay2 won't do).

How do I migrate from one storage driver to another, so that any containers which were starting automatically are still present and start automatically?

Comment: See also: https://serverfault.com/questions/686960/move-docker-data-images-and-containers-to-separate-drive-with-different-fs -- this isn't a duplicate, as the linked question has different specifics, but the answer there should be useful here too.

Answer (score -1):

Subvolumes typically don't require a ton of work (in theory based on the fedora docs for btrfs) - should be able to `rm -r /var/lib/docker/subvolumes/*` but for some reason - docker **dark** magic - this doesn't work.

**TLDR: I used the following script I found [on this gist](https://gist.github.com/hopeseekr/cd2058e71d01deca5bae9f4e5a555440)** to remove all sub volumes in `/var/lib/docker/btrfs/subvolumes`

- I modified it slightly to include the `echo "Deleting: $subvolume"` just to make sure I wasn't going to torch my entire system

! Before running this, make sure you have bind mounted all your important data in your containers to your host because the following will remove all container layers.

```bash
for subvolume in /var/lib/docker/btrfs/subvolumes/*; do
    echo "Deleting: $subvolume"
    # Uncomment the next line after you've verified the list is correct.
    # btrfs subvolume delete $subvolume
done
```

Comment: Not sure how this is supposed to answer the question asked.  Seems to be a method to delete all of your docker containers when using using the btrfs driver, which isn't what was asked for.